# How do I write f(x)=P(X <=x) for -∞ <x<∞?

Tags: math-mode

This is how I did it. It shows an error.

```
$F(x)=P[X \leq x]$ \quad \text{for} \quad -\infty \leq x \leq \infty
```

Comment: put $ in the end, $F(x)=P[X \leq x] \quad \text{for} \quad -\infty \leq x \leq \infty$

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Comment: Type `$F(x)=P[X\leq x]$ for $-\infty \leq x \leq \infty$` as they are two formulas separated by text.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three possibilities. The first possibility uses two separate formulas, with the word "for" typeset in ordinary text mode. The second and third possibilities use a single formula; they differ only in the amount of whitespace by which the word "for" is separated from the surrounding math material. Observe that in both the second and third row, it is necessary to encase the `-` symbol that precedes `\infty` in curly braces, in order to inform TeX that the symbol should be typeset as a unary and not as a binary operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
$F(x)=P[X \leq x]$ for $-\infty \leq x \leq \infty$

$F(x)=P[X \leq x] \text{ for }{-}\infty \leq x \leq \infty$

$F(x)=P[X \leq x]\quad\text{for}\quad{-}\infty \leq x \leq \infty$
\end{document}
```